# Cannot establish a connection to the server

Tags: sql-server

I just fixed my computer here and there after I was facing some BSOD's and when I now try to open up SQL Server using Windows Authentication, displays the following message and doesn't login.

> TITLE: Connect to Server
>
> Cannot connect to SARIN-PC\SQLEXPRESS.
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> A network-related or instance-specific
>   error occurred while establishing a
>   connection to SQL Server. The server
>   was not found or was not accessible.
>   Verify that the instance name is
>   correct and that SQL Server is
>   configured to allow remote
>   connections. (provider: SQL Network
>   Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating
>   Server/Instance Specified) (Microsoft
>   SQL Server, Error: -1)

I checked in the Configuration Manager, Named Pipes, Shared Memory and TCP/IP all are enabled. What went wrong now? :-|

Comment: This checklist might help you: http://www.sqlmusings.com/2009/03/11/resolving-a-network-related-or-instance-specific-error-occurred-while-establishing-a-connection-to-sql-server/

Comment: maybe try asking on serverfault.com

Comment: Can it be something related to SQL Service not started. How can I start this?

Comment: Assuming you're on some recent Windows version... Administrative Tools > Services > SQL Server > Start, perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you check SQL Server Configuration Manager->SQL Service(MSSQL). Is it runnig?

You also can check:

1. SQL Service(MSSQL)->Properties->Service->Host Name is eqals to "Service Name"
   which you must enter when you start your MSSQL Manadgment Studio.
2. If it don`t help you can read this articlea http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2007/05/13/sql-network-interfaces-error-26-error-locating-server-instance-specified.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are typing in the right computer name and instance name. The error basically points to that.

Comment: But it used to login just somedays ago and now it's not. The computer name is the same :-/

Comment: i had similiar issue when i change my computer name..so was suggesting that...but check in configuration manager if instances aree running and there are no firewall blocking.really it should be something small and silly...also see the checklist by Martin